# String concatenation attempt causing unexpected error

Tags: python

I'm new to python and overflow so bear with me please.

```py
import time
import datetime
    
now =  datetime.datetime.now()
   
if str(now.hour<12):
    print(str(now.hour -  12 + ":"))
```

```
error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: you have to modify the print statement a bit.    print(str(now.hour -  12) + ":")

Comment: if you surround your code with 3 backticks(```) or indent it all, it will be displayed as code, so much easier for us all to see :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
print(str(now.hour -  12) + ":")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the code as follows:

```
import time
import datetime

now =  datetime.datetime.now()

if str(now.hour<12):
    print(str(now.hour -  12) + ":") #moved parenthesis inside
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the bigger problem is that you are casting to string in your if condition. Since a non empty string will be truthy, your condition will always result in true. The code should be:

```
import time
import datetime
    
now =  datetime.datetime.now()
   
if now.hour < 12:
    print(str(now.hour -  12) + ":"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got your parenthesis in the wrong place.  You want

```
str(now.hour-12)+":"
```